# How to install Google Docs extension in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to install a Google Docs extension in Libreoffice such that I can import and export all my documents to and fro. I have tried [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/libreoffice-google-docs-sync-addon.html) but they don't seem to work properly. Is there an updated version of these instructions to install Google Docs extension in the Libreoffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I installed `ooo2gd` the following way. Install `JRE` and `libreoffice-java-common`

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre libreoffice-java-common
```

Then download [ooo2gd](http://code.google.com/p/ooo2gd/downloads/list) latest and do

```
unopkg add PATH/ooo2gd_3.0.0.oxt
```

Then start Libreoffice.

[image: Toolbar]

[image]

Comment: I had to use `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/unopkg.bin` instead of `unopkg` to install the extension on Ubuntu 12.04